# Move/Copy Document Libraries from Sharepoint v3.0 to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2010

My company has moved to TFS 2010.  We have a new Sharepoint server (Sharepoint 2010 with Enterprise Client Access License) for our new TFS Server.

But there are a lot of documents we would like to move from our old Sharepoint v3.0 server.  We don't want to move all the documents, but we do want to move a lot of them.

I had heard that Explorer View can make this easy, but I tried this and it does not seem to work for our Sharepoint v3.0 server (even after I enabled and started the "WebClient" service on the server).

So, my question is this: Is there an easy way to move/copy large amounts of Documents (only documents) from a Sharepoint v3.0 site to Sharepoint 2010 site?

Comment: Whats the issue with explorer view? I'd try to fix that as it's the easiest way to copy many files out of WSS 3.0. Try using it in 32-bit Windows XP with IE 7.

Comment: Explorer view has been messed up by MS in IE8 and IE9. Incredibly they don't offer any solution. Daniel is right, try it out in a vm with an older install.

Comment: Codeplex has a tool which will permit you to do this - its got a steep learning curve but it does work. http://spmigration.codeplex.com/. We used it as the base for a tool we wrote to migrate a specific installation - over 100Gb of docs migrated without incident.